# вложенные таблицы в sql

Tags: mysql

ищу как создать вложенную таблицу mysql, но везде предлагается вариант с oracle
у меня mysql 5.5.53

какой тип данных надо определить для ячейки чтоб туда засунуть таблицу

Comment: нет такого типа данных. делаете отдельную таблицу из которой по id ссылаетесь на запись основной таблицы. даже в oracle, где они есть, в 99% случаев их использование не целесообразно

Comment: Нет такого в MySQL. Можно было бы сериализовать, скажем, в XML или JSON - но версия старовата...

Comment: благодарю Вас за ответы